# How to get req.params from GET route in POST route

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am struggling with one issue for really long time. I can't 'transfer' `req.params.token` and `req.params.id` to the POST route. What I mean:

```
router.get('/passwordReset/:token/:id', isNotLogin, (req, res) => {
console.log('token: ' + req.params.token)
console.log('id: ' + req.params.id)
    Token.findOne({userId: req.params.id}, function (err, id) {
        if (!id) {
            res.redirect('/confirmError');
        } else {
            res.render('view/password/passwordReset');
        };
    });
});
```

Results from console.log are (e.g.):

- token: 934f569631026e396da5b9a952bfsnx72ba1d2187ecd734b47b3aca89640faf3
- id: 60e5560119fcb9627sgar810

Example link:

- https://localhost:3000/passwordReset/934f569631026e396da5b9a952bfsnx72ba1d2187ecd734b47b3aca89640faf3/60e5560119fcb9627sgar810

But when it comes to the POST route:

```
router.post('/passwordReset/:token/:id', isNotLogin, async (req, res) => {
console.log('token: ' + req.params.token)
console.log('id: ' + req.params.id)
    await resetPassword(req.params.id, req.params.token, req.body.password);
});
```

The results of console.log are:

- token: :token
- id: :id

And that's what I can't solve. I've tried many things, but I just can't come to the right solution.

I've already tried to replace `router.post('/passwordReset/:token/:id'` to `router.post('/passwordReset'` but it didn't help.

Form for the password reset:

```
<form action="/passwordReset/:token/:id" method="POST">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <button type="submit">Zmień hasło</button>
</form>
```

And the `resetPassword` function:

```
async function resetPassword(userId, token, password) {
    const passwordResetToken = await Token.findOne({userId: userId});
    if (!passwordResetToken) {throw new Error("Invalid password reset token");}
    const isValid = await bcrypt.compare(token, passwordResetToken.token);
    if (!isValid) throw new Error("Invalid password reset token");
    const salt = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
    const hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 100000, 64, 'sha512').toString('hex');
    await User.updateOne(
        {_id: userId},
        {$set: {hash: hash}},
        {$set: {salt: salt}},
        {new: true}
    );
    const user = await User.findById({_id: userId});
    sendEmail(user.username, "Password Reset Successfully", {email}, "./email/template/resetPassword.handlebars");
    await passwordResetToken.deleteOne();
    return true;
};
```

The error is:
`(node:1811) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" (type string) at path "userId" for model "Token"`

Whole code: https://github.com/kbilak/ToDoApp

Comment: You have `<form action="/passwordReset/:token/:id" method="POST">` in your HTML. You need to insert the actual values into the `action` url. You can do this by adding a `submit` event handler to the form and calling `this.setAttribute('action', url);` inside the function.

Comment: Thank You for Your comment. I've tried this and it still seems not to be working. It now looks like this `<form action="/passwordReset/:token/:id" method="POST" id="form">` and script `<script>function fct() {
    form.setAttribute('action', url)
}
const form = document.getElementById('form')
this.addEventListener('submit', fct)</script>`. Correct me if I'm doing something wrong, but I think it's right way to do it. I've done it other way also, but the error was the same.

Comment: The form doesn't have an id so `document.getElementById('form')` won't work. Also, `url` has to be actually composed by you; calling the function as it is will cause an UnnownReference error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the actual value for token and id to the html page. So your form action should be something like this when you inspect the code on your browser

/passwordReset/934f569631026e396da5b9a952bfsnx72ba1d2187ecd734b47b3aca89640faf3/60e5560119fcb9627sgar810

Using the ejs template format

```
<form action="/passwordReset/<%= token %>/<%= id %>" method="POST">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <button type="submit">Zmień hasło</button>
</form>
```

In order to send the value to your html page, you need to add those value when you are rendering the page. Just like you have it here

```
router.get('/passwordReset/:token/:id', isNotLogin, (req, res) => {
token = req.params.token
id =req.params.id
    Token.findOne({userId: req.params.id}, function (err, id) {
        if (!id) {
            res.redirect('/confirmError');
        } else {
            res.render('view/password/passwordReset', {
token: token
id: id
} );
        };
    });
});
```